# jQuery draggable - drag guide line contaiment

Tags: jquery, draggable

I got 3 divs that are basically just rectangles. One is at the top right, second on bottom right, third on bottom left.

All of them are same size and have same distance between them and all of them are draggable.

I want to connect all 3 divs with lines (this would make it like a triangle), and then make it so that the user could only drag the divs along these lines. Top right div could only be draggable down, bottom right div only draggable to the left, and bottom left box could only be draggable to the top at the angle of 45 degrees.

Just wondering if this can be done with just jQuery or jQuery plugins? I saw some similar stuff being done using `svg`, but it seemed very complicated to achieve for what im trying to do here.

Any suggestions?

Edit: i know there is a restriction for drag by axis (this would solve the restrict down and right problem), is there a way to restrict by xy at 45 degrees?